# Dynamic Shader Linkage in DirectX12?

Tags: shaders, directx, directx11, directx12

Do the dynamic shader linking concepts introduced in DirectX11 ShaderModel 5.0 still work in DirectX12? In the documentation the reflection API is still available (e.g. `ID3D12LibraryReflection`), claiming it is provided especially for the shader linking technology, but I couldn't find other important interfaces like `ID3D11FunctionLinkingGraph` or `ID3D11ClassLinkage` in DX12.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. They are provided in the D3DCompile library: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd607342(v=vs.85).aspx